Kubuntu 24.04 LTS (KDE Plasma v5.27.11) NVIDIA with Wayland: Not Using NVIDIA GPU
I'm running Kubuntu 24.04 with KDE Plasma v5.27.11 and NVIDIA Driver Version 555.42.02 (CUDA v12.5) on an XPS 15 9520 with a NVIDIA 3050 Ti Mobile GPU. I've managed to get GPU acceleration for ML using CUDA or other things working and I've followed the instructions on the KDE website.
The problem I'm now encountering is that Wayland doesn't seem to be using the dedicated GPU but rather my CPUs internal one. Although I tried I couldn't find any resources regarding the process of checking whether my suspicion is actually correct and how to fix my problem. I am, however, fairly certain that I'm correct as the nvidia-smi command doesn't show any processes using the GPU at all, in contrast to X11 showing up when not using Wayland:
➜  ~ nvidia-smi
Wed Jul 10 18:03:45 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 555.42.02              Driver Version: 555.42.02      CUDA Version: 12.5     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 ...    Off |   00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   49C    P0             10W /   35W |       1MiB /   4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                        
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

(output when running nvidia-smi on Wayland session)

I really don't think its that similar, I'am trying to get it working and I have encountered a (more or less) specific problem when trying to get Wayland to work with Nvidia, as far as I can tell the other Thread was about the question of feasibility when it comes to Nvidia+Wayland. X11 isn't really an option for me as I just can't do without Wayland's vastly superior Multi Monitor Support, espsecially when working with more then one resolution.
